# Provide limited shared access to objects

Tags: security

I'm working on a system integrating Infor LN and Salesforce using the Inforce app.

All SF records sync'd with LN are of an Inforce Account Record Type.

The accounts have the usual CRM features plus access to all invoices and sales transactions (parent:child - account:invoice object, etc.)

Within the enterprise there are several divisions and, due to security considerations, users can only see the accounts that they own and those within their division.

The problem I have is that some of the sales team interact with accounts that "belong" to a different division due to the customers diverse product range.  Unfortunately the security restrictions prevent the user from logging any of these interactions.

The stakeholders have now consented to share access to all accounts across all divisions, however this is to be limited purely the general CRM components, not invoice details, etc.

Can anyone advise of a good way to achieve this?  Would different page layouts be possible, or is there something else that I should consider, such as limiting sharing of the child objects?

Unfortunately I'm the only resource here with knowledge of SF so I could do with some guidance from the forum.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've been trying to resolve this problem with different security settings but I'm having no joy.  The big problem seems to be that the Invoice custom object is in a Master-Detail relationship to the Account object.  The access to Invoices is therefore inherited from account sharing.  Without this avenue and with the integration reliant on the record type (therefore limiting record type page layout options), is there any other option available to me?

Comment: Would some form of visual force page be the way to go - replacing the standard account?